# Manipulating a user input string in MapReduce

Tags: java, string, hadoop, input, mapreduce

I am beginning to use the Hadoop variant of MapReduce and therefore have zero clue about the ins and outs. I understand how conceptually it's supposed to work.

My problem is to find a specific search string within a bunch of files I have been provided. I am not interested about the files - that's sorted. But how would you go about asking for input? Would you ask within the JobConf section of the program? If so, how would I pass the string into the job?

If it's within the `map()` function, how would you go about implementing it? Wouldn't it just ask for a search string every time the `map()` function is called?

Here's the main method and `JobConf()` section that should give you an idea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // This produces an output file in which each line contains a separate word followed by
    // the total number of occurrences of that word in all the input files.

    JobConf job = new JobConf();

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("input"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("output"));

    // Output from reducer maps words to counts.
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    // The output of the mapper is a map from words (including duplicates) to the value 1.
    job.setMapperClass(InputMapper.class);

    // The output of the reducer is a map from unique words to their total counts.
    job.setReducerClass(CountWordsReducer.class);

    JobClient.runJob(job);
}
```

And the `map()` function:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

    // The key is the character offset within the file of the start of the line, ignored.
    // The value is a line from the file.

    //This is me trying to hard-code it. I would prefer an explanation on how to get interactive input!
    String inputString = "data"; 
    String line = value.toString();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (line.contains(inputString)) {
            String line1 = scanner.next();
            output.collect(new Text(line1), new LongWritable(1));
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

I am led to believe that I don't need a reducer stage for this problem. Any advice/explanations much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JobConf`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html) class is an extension of [`Configuration`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) class, and thus, you can set custom properties:

```
JobConf job = new JobConf();
job.set("inputString", "data");
...
```

Then, as atated in the documentation for the [Mapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html): *Mapper implementations can access the JobConf for the job via the JobConfigurable.configure(JobConf) and initialize themselves.* This means you have to re-implement such a method within your Mapper in order to get the desired parameter:

```
private static String inputString;

public void configure(JobConf job)
    inputString = job.get("inputString");
}
```

Anyway, this is using the old API. With the new one it is easier to access the configuration since the context (and thus the configuration) is passed to the `map` method as an argument.

Comment: Good explanation - just two things. In the 'job.set()' method you pass 'data' as a parameter. My data is all in files that are already in the input path so what would I put in there? 

Secondly, in the configure method you write 'test'. Is that just supposed to be a placeholder string or does 'test' have any special meaning?

Comment: Regarding the second question, is was an error by me, fixed :) About the first one, the example shows you how to pass to the mapper a parameter that is called "inputString" and whose value is "data", because that was the searching string you hardcoded in your code; but replace it by any other string that the user may pass as an argument of the main method.